# Update selected rows with value in table by using a checkbox for each row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have tried searched, but I am missing somthing or not phrasing myself correctly I guess.

php, sql and Codeigniter.

What I have is a list of reports in a database.

Theese have a column that states if they are "active" 1 or 0.

What I want to do is add a checkbox on the list that prints the rows in my view as that I can select and then when I have selected the rows I want to be able to press a button and by sending form data change the selected rows in the database to a 1 or 0.

example of how I am thinking of presenting it:

```
echo "<form action='' method='POST'><table>";

foreach($reports->result() as $row)
{ 
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td><input type="checkbox" name=""></td>;
   echo "<td>".$row->name."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row->time."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row->spot."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row->priority."</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
} 

echo "<tr><td colspan='5'><input type='submit'></td></tr>";
echo "</table></form>";
```

What would be the best is if I could get the checkboxes I select into a array for example that would be lovely.

I have tried with array_push, but I could not find a way to select only the ones I selected to send. Is there some way to do this that I dont know of?

Comment: How far did you get by yourself? Do you have any code to show that you are having difficulties with?

Comment: Not really come anywhere. I tried with array_push however I didnt manage to get it singled out to the ones I wanted, but I could use it to do it on all. I added som start code for what I am comming from. I am at a loss here. I have not found anything that really come close to do what I need..

Comment: checkboxes, how to create and populate in CI: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_checkbox

Comment: @Vickel That gave me close to nothing. Only a way to create a form with better code... And if there are some pointer in this link that tells how to stack checked checkboxes value in an array to a post-result I have yet to find it. But thanks for the input anyways. I will start using that to create forms instead.

Comment: `checked` is the 3rd parameter in form_checkbox(), so when you populate your form, you set this either to true or false, depending on the data ("active") you retrieve from database

Comment: @Vickel, Yes. And then? How do I send that data through a form? In my next step I need to insert this into the database on all rows that I selected.

Comment: @Vickel Please read into my issue again before posting again. This adds nothing to the issue I am having.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to make the selected checkboxes into an array by adding id[] to all checkboxes name like this this:

```
form_checkbox('id[]',$row->id, FALSE);
```

I loop out alot of these and might get this for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="12340">
<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="12353">
<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="12367">
<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="12389">
<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="12391">
```

Then in my controller I added this where my form takes action to and loops through the ones that I have checked and take action on them.

```
$arr = array();
if(!empty($_POST['id'])) {
    foreach($_POST['id'] as $selected) {
        $this->db->where('id', $selected);
        $this->db->update('rapporter' , $data);
    }
}else{}
```

This is working great for me. Now I only update the rows I have checked!

If someone have a more efficient way of doing this I am all ears!